Redirection from share point site to custom web application
There is classic sharePoint site(site A) hosted in sharepoint online. There are some custom web parts configured in this site. We have developed new web application to replace this site(site B). We want to redirect to site B on load of site A so that no need to delete site A and users will swiftly redirect to site B.

You can add to the SiteA a piece of javascript that redirects the user to antoher site, something like location.href = SiteB

Thanks Nik, but am not Sharepoint developer and informed by vendor that sharepoint site cannot be redirected with .net portal on load. Is this understanding correct?


From the home page of the site where you want to implement the URL click in New
From the menu click in News link



Create a redirect page using a SharePoint news link



Type the URL of the page to where the user should be redirected
Create a redirect page using a SharePoint news link
Click Post
Click in the cog icon in the suite bar and then Site Contents



Open the Site Pages library
Locate the page you have just created, click in the … next to the
name and then click in Make homepage
Create a redirect page using a SharePoint news link

This will make the home page of the site collection redirect to the new location, if you don’t want it to show in the news you will need to execute the following script using PnP PowerShell.
In order to accomplish the steps described in this article you must install the latest version of the PnP PowerShell module, more information about how to do it can be found here.

Open the PowerShell command line

Execute the following cmdlet to connect to the SharePoint site
collection where the redirect page was created
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://contoso.sharepoint.com

Execute the script below and update the $listItemID value and use
your own
$listItemID = 42
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Identity $listItemID -Values @{
"PromotedState"=0;
}



By executing this script your news link redirect page will be removed from the SharePoint news without losing its main purpose.
